# Shell command to Find a modified file by specific user

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am looking for a file modified by a specific user.
This user is not the owner of the file.

-uid param for find command is related to the owner of the file and not the user that perform the modification.

thank you

Comment: The question is unrelated to SSH, the [`find`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) command is stand-alone. And no, there is no way of finding files modified by a specific user because the filesystem doesn't save that information (at least no filesystem I know of).

Comment: Only chance as I see it, is if you knew which program edited the file. If you're lucky the program might log what it does, or leave a trace behind such as a tilde file, .history file etc, but as mentioned above, FS doesn't keep the information (reading journal in ext4 FS is probably not an option).